# How to go back to a previous view in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Depending on the navigation, I need the web page to return me to one view or another.

Let's say there are 3 views: View 1, View 2, and View 3. Both view 1 and 2 go to 3, but view 2 has a list, and when I click a button that goes to view 3, the list is saved. and not lose it, and when you go back from view 3 to 2, the same list appears. The problem is that the list is dynamic, so I have to store it inside some list in the controller (or at least that's the only thing I can think of). What I was trying to do is have a global `List<model> ListaGlobal;`, and when I look up the list in the database, I set `listGlobal` equal to the list fetched from the database.

And well, depending on the previous view, I will have the 1-3-1 or 2-3-2 navigation. I already have the 1-3-1 navigation.

What I was trying is, for example if I'm in view 2, save in a `ViewData["PrevView"] = "view2"`, pass it to the controller and then when I'm in view 3 use a helper:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BackPreviousView", "Home", new { view = ViewData["PreviousView"] }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Back" type="submit"/>
}
```

and this is how the controller receives it:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ReturnPreviousView(string view)
{
    if (view != "view2")
    {
        return View("View2", GlobalList);
    }
    return View("View1");
}
```

But I think I'm making it very difficult for myself, besides the fact that the list in view 2 is not being saved. There must be 1000 different ways, but that's what comes to my mind right now.

Eh trying to create a global list:

```
List<model> globalList;
```

and then the `ReturnPreviousView` method would look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ReturnPreviousView()
{
    try
    {
        if (globalList == null || globalList.Count == 0)
        {
            returnView("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View("FilterDate", _deliveries);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I assign a value to `globalList` when I search the database for the necessary elements:

```
List<DeliveryViewModel> deliveriesViewModels = new List<DeliveryViewModel>();

query = "query";
deliveriesViewModels = SelectByDate(query);
globalList = new List<DeliveryViewModel>();
globalList = deliveriesViewModels;
```

The list is brought from the database from a filter by date of view 1, that is, I enter a range of dates, the data in that range is searched, and it is displayed in a table in view 2. When I click on a row, I am redirected to view 3, but I do not want to query the database again, I want to save the table in a list and thus avoid making another query.

Comment: You could use the `Session` to store a list of the user's page navigation history. When reaching the `ReturnPreviousView()` method, you retrieve the second-last item in the list and that's the redirect data / view name

Comment: Each request is a connection to a URL with a response which is a view.  So to keep more than one view you need more than one instance of the request and then you will have a separate response and a view for each URL.

Comment: Is the list a multiselect or single select? What are they selecting in the view 2?

Comment: I will edit the question

Comment: the list is brought from the database from a filter by date of view 1, that is, I enter a range of dates, the data in that range is searched, and it is displayed in a table in view 2. So when I do clicking on a row, I am redirected to view 3, but I do not want to query the database again, I want to save the table in a list and thus avoid making a query

Comment: How about solving the problem in javascript? Store the view2 search form url in `window.sessionStorage`. Then on page load of view3, if there's a value in this store, change the href of the back button...